# Android Development 64 bit - Eclipse issues

Tags: android, eclipse

I recently decided to make another application for the Android but I am having severe Eclipse issues. I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit edition and my Eclipse keeps force closing whenever I try to do random things (such as saving, opening a file, building, etc). It does it randomly, I can sometimes save / run my application fine but other times whenever I save a file it just force closes. I've tried 32bit (because 64 bit was having this problem) but 32bit had even worse problems. I don't receive any errors at all, it just force closes. Sometimes it will lock up and say Java SE Binary has stopped responding.

Edit: After I just got done typing this I went into Eclipse and tried typgin android:padding and it force closed...

Comment: Run a virus check. Remove/clean the JDK and any Java on the machine, and install only Java 32 and anything 32. I have on same OS and 32 is just working fine.

Comment: Not that it's particularly helpful except to say that the problems you're encountering must be due to some more specific details, but I'm running 64bit Win 7 Ultimate with 32bit Eclipse, and I haven't encountered any issues like this.

Comment: My virus scan this morning yielded nothing, I've completely removed Java 2 times (Once when installing 64bit JDK and once installing 32bit JDK) but I still encountered problems. 32 bit wasn't randomly force closing but it did have a PermGen space error that caused me to close the program.

Comment: I tried to install everything 64bit as well and never got it to work. I ended up installing the 32bit JRE and 32bit eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

While I never did fix my 64 bit issues, I switched back to 32 bit and changed the PermGen space via shortcut command and it appears to be working...